# I'm trying to prove the chiral invariance of $\bar\psi\gamma_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\psi$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

Considering the chiral transformation

$\psi' = \gamma_{5}\psi$

and since $\psi$ is the Dirac spinor, the adjoint spinor can be written as $\bar\psi = \psi^{\dagger}\gamma^{0}$, then:

$
(\bar\psi\gamma_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\psi)' = \psi'^{\dagger} \gamma_{0}\gamma_{\mu}\partial^{\mu} = (\gamma_{5}\psi)^{\dagger}\gamma_{0}\gamma_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}(\gamma_{5}\psi) = \psi^{\dagger}\gamma_{5}\gamma_{0}\gamma_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\gamma_{5}\psi
$

Using the anti-commutation relation {$\gamma_{\mu}, \gamma_{5}$} = $0$:

$
= -\psi^{\dagger}\gamma_{0}\gamma_{5}\gamma_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\gamma_{5}\psi = -\bar\psi\gamma_{5}\gamma_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\gamma_{5}\psi
$

But I don't know how to evolve from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anticommutator again: $\{\gamma_\mu,\gamma_5\} \implies \gamma_5\gamma_\mu = -\gamma_\mu\gamma_5$, so $-\bar\psi\gamma_5\gamma_\mu\partial^\mu\gamma_5\psi = \bar\psi\gamma_\mu\gamma_5\partial^\mu\gamma_5\psi$

Since $\gamma_5$ is constant it commutes with $\partial^\mu$ so you get $\bar\psi\gamma_\mu\partial^\mu\gamma_5\gamma_5\psi$ = $\bar\psi\gamma_\mu\partial^\mu\psi$. (since $(\gamma_5)^2 = I$)